# How can I move data from spreadsheet to a database through SQL

Tags: sql, database, google-sheets, sql-workbench-j

I want to move the data from a spreadsheet into a database. The program I am using is called SQLWorkbenchJ. I am kinda of lost and don't really know where to start. Is there any tips or ways that might point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you trying to insert data from a spreadsheet into a table? Or trying to attach a spreadsheet from the database? You should edit your question to show us the spreadsheet. It's hard to help you if you don't provide the data source.

Answer (score 0):

Sql Workbench/J provides the `WbImport`command in order to load a text file into a DB table. So if you save your spreadsheet file in the CSV (comma separed value) format you can then load it in a table using this command.

Here is an example to load the text file `CLASSIFICATION_CODE.csv`having `,`as field delimiter and `^` as quoting character in the `CLASSIFICATION_CODE`DB table.

```
WbImport -type=text
-file='C:\dev\CLASSIFICATION_CODE.csv'
-delimiter=,
-table=CLASSIFICATION_CODE
-quoteChar=^
-badfile='C:\dev\rejected'
-continueOnError=true
-multiLine=true
-emptyStringIsNull=false;
```

You might not need all the parameters of the example. Refer to the [documentation](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/) to find the ones you need.

If the data you have in your spreadsheet are heterogeneous (e.g. your spreadsheet has two books) then split them in two files in order to store them in separate DB tables.

Comment: SQL Workbench can also import ODS, XLS and XLSX files directly: http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/command-import.html#spreadsheet-import you can also import a specific workbook from such a file, no need to split it